# Firefox Autocomplete on Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, autocomplete

**In my Component `LoginCard` I have a form, depending on whatever value comes from `props.active`, either `loginForm` or `registerForm` will render.**

**I have set seperate keys on the form, set autocomplete on the password input (this is the input causing the issue) to various different values.**

- `autocomplete="off"`
- `autocomplete="new-password"`
- `autocomplete="none"`
- `autocomplete="false"`
- `autocomplete="something-else"`

When switching from the login tab to the sign up tab (updating `props.active` to render new form), the password input will autocomplete and the input above will autocomplete to be a suggested email.

Firefox seems to be the only browser this occurs on.

I have a [CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3mx372jm) to test out in Firefox. You will need to do the following:

1. Go to the [CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3mx372jm) Link
2. Enter an email address and password into the Login inputs
3. Click Login
4. Firefox will then prompt you to save your password you **MUST** do this to replicate my issue
5. You may need to reload the page. The login inputs will now autocomplete (This is the desired behaviour and needs to be the case)
6. Now if you navigate to the sign up tab, the surname input will populate with the email address and the password input will populate with the password value

[image: Login Tab]
[image: Firefox autocomplete]

My Component for reference

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import _ from "lodash";

import InputControl from "./InputControl";
import InputButton from "./InputButton";
import FormControl from "./FormControl";

const LoginCard = props => {
  const [hideContent, setHideContent] = useState(false);

  const [emailSignUpRef, setEmailSignUpRef] = useState("");
  const [firstNameSignUpRef, setFirstNameSignUpRef] = useState("");
  const [surnameSignUpRef, setsurnameSignUpRef] = useState("");
  const [passwordSignUpRef, setPasswordSignUpRef] = useState("");
  const [confirmPasswordSignUpRef, setConfirmPasswordSignUpRef] = useState("");

  let registerEmailInput = "";
  let firstNameInput = "";
  let surNameInput = "";
  let passwordInput = "";
  let confirmPasswordInput = "";
  let checkBoxSignUp = "";
  let signUpBtn = "";

  const scrollToEl = _.debounce(
    el =>
      window.scrollTo({
        top: el,
        behavior: "smooth"
      }),
    1000
  );

  const handleOnFocus = event => {
    scrollToEl(event.target);
    setEmailSignUpRef(registerEmailInput.value);
    setFirstNameSignUpRef(firstNameInput.value);
    setsurnameSignUpRef(surNameInput.value);
    setPasswordSignUpRef(passwordInput.value);
    setConfirmPasswordSignUpRef(confirmPasswordInput.value);
    setHideContent(true);
  };

  const handleOnInput = () => {
    setEmailSignUpRef(registerEmailInput.value);
    setFirstNameSignUpRef(firstNameInput.value);
    setsurnameSignUpRef(surNameInput.value);
    setPasswordSignUpRef(passwordInput.value);
    setConfirmPasswordSignUpRef(confirmPasswordInput.value);
  };

  const handleOnBlur = event => {
    const rl = event.relatedTarget;
    if (
      !(firstNameInput === rl) &&
      !(surNameInput === rl) &&
      !(passwordInput === rl) &&
      !(confirmPasswordInput === rl) &&
      !(registerEmailInput === rl) &&
      !(checkBoxSignUp === rl) &&
      !(signUpBtn === rl)
    ) {
      setHideContent(
        !_.isEmpty(emailSignUpRef.trim()) ||
          !_.isEmpty(firstNameSignUpRef.trim()) ||
          !_.isEmpty(surnameSignUpRef.trim()) ||
          !_.isEmpty(passwordSignUpRef.trim()) ||
          !_.isEmpty(confirmPasswordSignUpRef.trim())
      );
    }
  };

  const loginForm = (
    <FormControl key={props.active}>
      <InputControl
        autoComplete="off"
        type="text"
        name="emailAddress"
        placeholder="Email address"
        label="Email Address"
      />
      <InputControl
        autoComplete="off"
        type="password"
        name="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        label="Password"
      />
      <InputControl type="checkbox" name="email" label="Keep me logged in" />
      <InputButton buttonText="Login" type="submit" />
    </FormControl>
  );

  const registerForm = (
    <FormControl key={props.active}>
      <InputControl
        refProp={input => {
          registerEmailInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onFocus={handleOnFocus}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        value={emailSignUpRef}
        autoComplete="off"
        type="text"
        name="emailAddressRegister"
        placeholder="Email address"
        label="Email Address"
      />
      <InputControl
        className={
          !hideContent ? "InputControl--hidden" : "InputControl--visible"
        }
        autoComplete="off"
        refProp={input => {
          firstNameInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="First Name"
        label="First Name"
      />
      <InputControl
        className={
          !hideContent ? "InputControl--hidden" : "InputControl--visible"
        }
        autoComplete="off"
        refProp={input => {
          surNameInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        type="text"
        name="surName"
        placeholder="Surname"
        label="Surname"
      />
      <InputControl
        className={
          !hideContent ? "InputControl--hidden" : "InputControl--visible"
        }
        autoComplete="new-password"
        refProp={input => {
          passwordInput = input;
        }}
        onInput={handleOnInput}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        type="password"
        name="passwordRegister"
        placeholder="Password"
        label="Password"
      />
      <InputControl
        refProp={input => {
          checkBoxSignUp = input;
        }}
        type="checkbox"
        name="checkboxRegister"
        label={["I have read and agreed to the terms and conditions"]}
      />
      <InputButton
        refProp={input => {
          signUpBtn = input;
        }}
        buttonText="Sign Up"
        type="submit"
      />
    </FormControl>
  );

  return (
    <div className="LoginCard">
      <h2
        className={
          "LoginCard-title" + (hideContent ? " LoginCard-titleHidden" : "")
        }
      >
        {props.active === "login" ? "Login" : "Sign Up"}
      </h2>
      {props.active === "login" ? loginForm : registerForm}
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(LoginCard);
```